# issue with importing same modul names

Tags: python, import, module

I have a tool which can execute bunch of unittests. In unittests some modules are imported for example "import models".

However in my executor I have also "models" module and from now on the tests are failing as python is looking for the source in my executor framework "models".

How can I solve this issue?

the issue is that: I have the executor framework which has a directory called "models" however this executor using unittest library can execute unittests and inside the unittest there is this following line of code: "import models" -> now the unittest is looking for stuff in my executor framework's "models" directory and not in its own source.

Structure:

```
ut-executor:
 models
  ...
 ut-executor -> this one is using unittest.TestLoader().discover(some_path + 'the-app-to-be-tested/uts')

the-app-to-be-tested:
src:
 models 
   ...
uts
   test_something.py
```

Here test_something.py adding src/models to path and doing "import models" however now its importing from ut-executor/models and not src/models.

Comment: Rename one of the modules? It's not clear to me what the issue is.

Comment: Are they external or internal modules? i.e. did you write the modules or did you install them with pip? If the former, simply `from dir1 import module as module1 from dir2 import module as module2`

Comment: It doesn't matter. I could rename it, however next time in a unittest might be a same module name again. I would like to avoid this monkey work.

Comment: @forgetso: the issue is not this... the issue is that:
I have the executor framework which has a directory called "models" however this executor using unittest library can execute unittests and inside the unittest there is this following line of code: "import models" -> now the unittest is looking for stuff in my executor framework's "models" directory and not in its own source.

Comment: @vpas, your question isn't clear. Please see [ask], then [edit] your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: @vpas an outline of the two directory structures, files, and code examples would be helpful.

Comment: is it better now?

Comment: I still think using `from` might help. Like `from src import models`. Does that work if you try it?

Comment: But I cannot ensure that all unittests will use from statement. Testcases are out of my control.